# Upload a InputStream to AWS s3 asynchronously (non-blocking) using AWS SDK for Java, version 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I am uploading `inputStream` object to s3 synchronously (blocking way) it works.

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().build();
s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream,STREAM_SIZE));
```

but when I try the same with `S3AsyncClient` there is no `.fromInputStream` method on `AsyncRequestBody`.

```
S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder().build();
s3AsyncClient.putObject(objectRequest, AsyncRequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream,STREAM_SIZE)); // error no method named 'fromInputStream'
```

And I can't use `.fromByteBuffer` as it will load the entire stream into memory, which I don't want.

I am interested why there is no method to read from InputStream in `AsyncRequestBody`. And Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Can you create a thread in the background to do the upload?

Comment: @stdunbar, but the background thread will be blocked till the upload right?
If I have multiple uploads, I'll be running out of threads quite quickly. the s3AsyncClient uses ReactiveStreams with does not block any thread.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the point - continue foreground processing and let the background thread take the time it needs.  I agree that the missing `.fromInputStream` doesn't quite make sense but ultimately the AWS SDK is creating a thread to handle async anyway and you can just handle it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research this is what I found :

1. InputStream is blocking on it's nature, So when you read from input stream some thread will be block, in case of [@jakobeha's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626819/10066692) answer '[toByteReadChannel](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-utils/ktor-utils/io.ktor.util.cio/to-byte-read-channel.html)' will return a read blocking Channel. so Considering Performance it is somewhat equivalent to Performing Sync S3Client.fromInputStream() in background Thread, you can do that by wrapping it in CompletableFuture.
2. Other "AsyncRequestBody" types like "FileAsyncRequestBody" uses 'nio' (non blocking I/O) with callbacks. Maybe that's why AWS team haven't included "fromInputStream" in "AsyncRequestBody" as it is simply not possible to use fully non-blocking way, and it would have caused confusion.
3. If you want a highly scalable solution, the best solution would be not to use InputStream all together, find where the InputStream is originated and use some alternative which support non blocking Channels, In my case I have used Java Flow and converted it to 'Publisher' and used AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher()

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Kotlin and coroutines: here is a kotlin wrapper which will create an asynchronous `AsyncRequestBody` from an `InputStream`. The wrapper will run in a background thread by default, but you can pass an explicit `CoroutineScope` and run it inside of your coroutine, which will avoid creating a separate thread.

```kotlin
import io.ktor.util.cio.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncRequestBody
import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.*

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
class StreamAsyncRequestBody(
  inputStream: InputStream,
  private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = GlobalScope
) :
  AsyncRequestBody {
  private val inputChannel =
    inputStream.toByteReadChannel(context = coroutineScope.coroutineContext)

  override fun subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<in ByteBuffer>) {
    subscriber.onSubscribe(object : Subscription {
      private var done: Boolean = false

      override fun request(n: Long) {
        if (!done) {
          if (inputChannel.isClosedForRead) {
            complete()
          } else {
            coroutineScope.launch {
              inputChannel.read {
                subscriber.onNext(it)
                if (inputChannel.isClosedForRead) {
                  complete()
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      private fun complete() {
        subscriber.onComplete()
        synchronized(this) {
          done = true
        }
      }

      override fun cancel() {
        synchronized(this) {
          done = true
        }
      }
    })
  }

  override fun contentLength(): Optional<Long> = Optional.empty()
}
```

Example usage:

```kotlin
suspend fun s3Put(objectRequest: PutObjectRequest, inputStream: InputStream) = coroutineContext {
  s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, StreamAsyncRequestBody(inputStream, this)
}
```

If you use Java, you will need to create your own wrapper and use a different coroutine library. Alternatively, you could create an `Executor` with a fixed number of threads: if you have too many uploads running at once, they will block one another, but they won't create too many threads and block the entire program.

---

**EDIT:** Fixed the code. I didn't test the previous version, I tested this version a few times to upload and it worked. Of course that doesn't mean it's bug-free though :)

Comment: Although you are using Kotlin language, you are still using the AWS SDK for Java - just to be clear here.

Comment: yes. Afaik there is no AWSSDK for Kotlin, but the java one is already pretty terse and there is a 1-liner to wrap `CompletableFuture` into a coroutine (still completed via AWS event-streams): `suspend fun <T> wrapAws2Suspend(awsResponse: CompletableFuture<T>): T = awsResponse.asDeferred().await()`